# Amplify Flutter: How to connect to existing GraphQL endpoint

Tags: flutter, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm implementing Amplify Flutter and want to connect it to our own custom GraphQL endpoint (i.e. non-AppSync). I am however having trouble getting it to work. The official documentation is not super-clear on this (at least not for those of us who are completely new to Amplify). What I have done:

1. In `pubspec.yaml`, I’ve added and installed the `amplify_api` package.
2. In `main.dart`, I’ve updated `_configureAmplify()` to add the `AmplifyAPI()` plugin.
3. In `amplifyconfiguration.dart`, I have manually added the following snippet:

```
"api": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsAPIPlugin": {
                "xxxxxAPI": {
                    "endpointType": "GraphQL",
                    "endpoint": "http://xxxxxxxx.eba-fmuh2afu.eu-north-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/query",
                    "region": "[REGION]",
                    "authorizationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting the error "*There is no API configured for this plugin with matching endpoint type.*"  What am I doing wrong?  (Note: I presume that I don't have to add any "region" value if I'm pointing to our own custom GraphQL endpoint).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by closing the app and uninstalling it, then run again and log in to start fetching API